# Virtual Host Forbidden after enabled SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I enabled SSL for my wamp64 server and it all works fine for http://localhost/ and https://localhost/.

But I didn't enable it to look at localhost - I need to activate for 1 of my virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/DEV/www/app/public/"
    ServerName dev.app.com:443
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ErrorLog "D:/wamp64/www/ssllogs/ssl_error.log"
    TransferLog "D:/wamp64/www/ssllogs/ssl_access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "D:/wamp64/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/wamp64/ssl.key/server.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "D:/DEV/www/app/public">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "D:/wamp64/www/ssllogs/ssl_request.log" \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course it still has this in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.app.com
    DocumentRoot d:/dev/www/app/public
    <Directory  "d:/dev/www/app/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, the `http` version works just fine, but `https` gives me:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.16 Server at dev.app.com Port 443
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<VirtualHost *:443>` * matches everything - it's a wildcard

you shouldn't include the port inside the virtual host, you have already set that.

```
ServerName dev.app.com:443
```

should be

```
ServerName dev.app.com
```

> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.17
>   (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.16 Server at dev.app.com Port 443

this is the result of a syntax error - syntax for Apache 2.4 has changed

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

becomes

```
Require all granted
```

see here for a full reference to access control syntax changes
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: I did not know that, will need to remember. I left the port, but changed the syntax and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In apache you can: set both two ports and two ways to connect simultaneously and both will work
you can set `<VirtualHost *:80>` in the file httpd-vhosts.conf
and at the same time `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` in the file httpd-ssl.conf
both will work fine
It all depends on what access permissions you give.
if you want to have access to both, set them both `Require all granted`