# Forbidden after enabling SSL

Tags: apache-2.4, django, certbot

I recently used LetsEncrypt's Certbot to enable SSL on my server. It's running Apache 2.4.18 with Django 1.11 on Ubuntu 16.04. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803081/certbot-apache-error-name-duplicates-previous-wsgi-daemon-definition), I duplicated my :80 VirtualHost definition for 443 in the same file. I am now getting 403 Forbidden whenever I try to access my site over HTTPS. Below is my current site conf file, lightly anonymized:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIDaemonProcess MyApp python-home=/home/Administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyRepo_env python-path=/home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp
WSGIProcessGroup MyApp

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.com

        ServerAdmin wouldntyou@liketoknow.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/static
        <Directory /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp/wsgi.py

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myapp.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName myapp.com

        ServerAdmin wouldntyou@liketoknow.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/static
        <Directory /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp.wsgi.py

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The only thing showing in the Apache log is `client denied by server configuration: /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp.wsgi.py`

What permissions do I need to modify, or what settings do I need to change to get it working over SSL?

Comment: I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/774819/virtual-host-forbidden-after-enabled-ssl) which looks like a similar issue, but was due to syntax errors I don't think I've made

Comment: 403 errors in your browser usually come (like most web **server** warnings and errors) with a much more verbose description in your server (error) log file - so start there

Comment: Unfortunately the message in error.log isn't much more helpful (to me at least). Just says "client denied by server configuration: /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp.wsgi.py"

Comment: You do  know that you added an extra `.com` to your `ServerName` directive. Is that a typo or is the same error actually in your config file?

Comment: Ah, oops. That is just a typo, not present in the config. I got a bit overzealous with find/replace apparently

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was frustrating. The issue ended up being a simple typo in my second VirtualHost definition. Specifically, the WSGIScriptAlias should be `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp/wsgi.py` not `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/administrator/Documents/MyRepo/MyApp/MyApp.wsgi.py`. The only difference is a period where there should have been a slash, between the final `MyApp` and `wsgi.py`. Hopefully someone else will read this and be spared the hours of nonsensical debugging.